# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does $\sigma(n^2)/q^k < q$ hold?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers

If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, then it is known that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right),$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.  (See this [paper](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) for a proof.)

Here is my question:

> Does $\sigma(n^2)/q^k < q$ hold?

**MY ATTEMPT**

It is easy to prove that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \neq q$. For suppose to the contrary that
$$q=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$
This means that
$$2n^2 = q\sigma(q^k)$$
which implies that $q \mid n^2$, contradicting $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

So now, assume that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k > q$.  We obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right)>q,$$
from which we get
$$2n^2 > \sigma(n^2) > q^{k+1}$$
$$2n^2 > q\sigma(q^k)$$
$$2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) > q\sigma(q^{k-1}) \geq q$$
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) > q,$$
whence I do not arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the conjecture $q^k < n$ is true (see [here (page 117)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1450.pdf), [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf), and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01591.pdf)), then it follows that $q < n$, so that if
$\sigma(n^2)/q^k < q$, then we obtain
$$\sigma(n^2) < q\cdot{q^k} < n\cdot{n} = n^2$$
which is a contradiction.

Also, if the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=1$ is true, then it follows that $q < n$, so that if $\sigma(n^2)/q^k < q$, then we have
$$\sigma(n^2) < q\cdot{q^k} = q\cdot{q} < n\cdot{n} = n^2$$
which again is a contradiction.

Hence, conjecturally we expect
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right) > q$$
to be true.